# A troubling MySQL Join operation

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Two tables, one containing questions the other containing each users answer, if they have answered it. I'm trying to pull the next question ordered by the weight (most important) where user a does not have an answer already in the answer table.

My tables look like this:

```
table: app_questions
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| owneruid | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| question | varchar(350) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| answer_1 | varchar(350) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| answer_2 | varchar(350) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| answer_3 | varchar(350) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| answer_4 | varchar(350) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| weight   | decimal(5,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| datetime | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |

table: app_answers
| id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uid                | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| quid               | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| answer             | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| importance         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| answer_status      | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| answer_explanation | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| datetime           | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

I have tried a few variations but have yet to get exactly what I need:

```
   SELECT  uid ,
        question ,
        answer_1 ,
        answer_2 ,
        answer_3 ,
        answer_4 ,
        weight ,
        answer_status
FROM    match_questions
        LEFT JOIN match_answers ON match_questions.id = match_answers.quid
WHERE   answer_status IS NULL
        AND EXISTS ( SELECT *
                     FROM   match_answers
                     WHERE  uid = 1 ) 
ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 1;   



    SELECT uid ,
        question ,
        answer_1 ,
        answer_2 ,
        answer_3 ,
        answer_4 ,
        weight ,
        answer_status
 FROM   match_questions
        LEFT JOIN match_answers ON match_questions.id = match_answers.quid
 WHERE  uid IS NULL
        AND answer_status IS NULL 
 ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 1;




 SELECT  uid ,
            question ,
            answer_1 ,
            answer_2 ,
            answer_3 ,
            answer_4 ,
            weight ,
            answer_status
    FROM    match_questions
            LEFT JOIN match_answers ON match_questions.id = match_answers.quid
    WHERE   answer_status IS NULL
            AND uid IS NULL 
    ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Can you create an sqlfiddle example, I am trying to do that but dont have sample data, You can copy and use it http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68aed

Comment: Sample data and sample (desired) output would make it much easier to answer this question.

Comment: thanks guys, peterm managed to help. I'll use sqlfiddle in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing sample data and desired output but IMHO your query might look like this

```
SELECT q.id,
       q.question,
       q.answer_1,
       q.answer_2,
       q.answer_3,
       q.answer_4,
       q.weight
  FROM match_questions q LEFT JOIN match_answers a
    ON q.id = a.quid
   AND a.uid = 1
 WHERE a.quid IS NULL
 ORDER BY q.weight, q.id
 LIMIT 1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39088/11)** demo

Comment: This was the ticket. Thank you for the help! Also I had no idea sqlfiddle existed, but that's great, next time I need help I'll use it and add some sample data.

Comment: +1 This is an "anti-join" pattern. A left join, to return all questions along with matching answers, and then a predicate to eliminate all the rows that had a match, so we are left with rows that didn't have a match. (I'd qualify the column reference to `uid` as `a.uid` as an aid to future readers, and to prevent an "ambiguous column" error in the event someone added a `uid` column on the questions table.)

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks for your input. Agreed. Answer and sqlfiddle example have been updated.

Comment: Ok I may have overstated when I said it was working as expected.  I've loaded sqlfiddle up with some data. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61499/1

there is one answer that was made on question 1 by user 1, so in theory i need to pull the next in line that user 1 has not answered orderd by weight. I'm still attempting to get it but haven't yet. Any ideas?

Comment: @cjaredrun Well, the problem with your sample data is that two questions with ids 2 and 3 both have weight 0. Therefore mysql decides on it's own what record to grab when you say `LIMIT 1`. To avoid this nondeterministic behavior **always** assign distinct weight values to your questions. As some sort of workaround to make the order deterministic even if you fail to assign distinct weight values is `ORDER BY q.weight, q.id`. Meaning if weights are equal grab first a row with the lowest id. I've updated answer and sqlfiddle.